# How to display a part of string from static position in that string with VBScript?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I have a list which I got from a database with VBScript (... means there is another code)

```
<%
...
for each x in rs.Fields
Response.Write(x & "<br />")
next
...
%>
```

and I got the following results for `x`:

```
Eventid=1289,EventActive=True,EventTemplate=13,FeatureEvent=True,EventTitle=BackToSchool,EventCompany=SummerKids
Eventid=981112,EventActive=True,EventTemplate=temp199,FeatureEvent=True,EventTitle=SummerSale 2015,EventCompany=KidsClothesOnSale
Eventid=A20BK913,EventActive=False,EventTemplate=green001,FeatureEvent=False,EventTitle=Example Event Title,EventCompany=TEST
Eventid=MO72221,EventActive=False,EventTemplate=817AA11,FeatureEvent=False,EventTitle=TEST TITLE FOR EVENT,EventCompany=SELF TEST
```

How can I display only EventTitle in each `x` like this with VBScript?

```
BackToSchool
Summer Sale 2015
Example Event Title
TEST TITLE FOR EVENT
```

Comment: What is your recordset schema?

Comment: it's not important, I got problem from write the string, and what I must do is  only take the string after = (in this case is the EventTitle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is consistent (always six comma-separated `key=value` pairs, no commas exist within your `key=value` pairs, etc), then you can just split the string on commas to get your `key=value` pairs, then split the 5th `key=value` pair on `=` to get just the value.

For example:

```
For Each x In rs.Fields
    kv = Split(x, ",")                   ' Get key=value pairs
    Response.Write Split(kv(4), "=")(1)  ' Output the value of the 5th pair
    Response.Write "<br>"
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to point out an alternative method, you could try using `InStr`, also...

As Bond stated, your CSV list is consistent, so you should be able to look up using something like this...

*(Please note that the following relies on the format that you've specified, so if spaces are added between commas or equal signs then you'll have problems.)*

```vbs
Const cDelim = ","
Const cEqual = "=" 

Function GetItemValueFromList(plist, itemName)
    Dim ip 'Item pointer
    Dim ep 'Equals sign pointer
    Dim pl, ni
    pl = cDelim & plist
    ni = cDelim & itemName & cEqual
    ip = InStr(pl, ni)
    'Just make sure we find something before we try pulling the value...
    If ip > 0 Then
        ep = Instr(ip+1, pl, cEqual)
        GetItemValueFromList = Mid(pl, ep+1, InStr(ep+1, pl, cDelim)-ep-1)
    Else
        GetItemValueFromList = ""
    End If
End Function
```

Thanks to Ekkehard.Horner for pointing out the obvious - I was obviously having a senior moment when I wrote that code.

Comment: The (one) search target should be "EventTitle=".

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner: Of course.  I just like to make my code that little more flexible. There are multiple name value pairs in each item and what's to say the OP won't want to use the code on a completely different list.

Comment: If you allow variations, your stragegy/code fails (silently!) for keywords having a prefix of "EventTitle". Given **fixed** keywords, extra search for "=" is a bad idea.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner: True. I'll adjust my answer.

Answer (score 0):

While [this answer by OP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32810918/447356) might work for the specific case, it's not very elegant and I prefer using a more generic method, using a Dictionary object.

The method is:

```
Function ParseData(rawString, mainDelimeter, subDelimeter)
    Dim oData, x, y
    Dim arrMainParts, arrSubParts
    Dim currentKey, currentValue
    Set oData = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    arrMainParts = Split(rawString, mainDelimeter)
    For x=0 To UBound(arrMainParts)
        arrSubParts = Split(arrMainParts(x), subDelimeter)
        If UBound(arrSubParts)>0 Then
            currentKey = arrSubParts(0)
            currentValue = arrSubParts(1)
            If oData.Exists(currentKey) Then
                oData(currentKey) = currentValue
            Else  
                oData.Add currentKey, currentValue
            End If
        End If
        Erase arrSubParts
    Next
    Erase arrMainParts
    Set ParseData = oData
End Function
```

And usage in this specific case would be:

```
For Each x In rs.Fields
    Set oData = ParseData(x, ",", "=")
    If oData.Exists("EventTitle") Then
        Response.Write(oData("EventTitle") & "<br />")
    End If
    Set oData = Nothing
Next
```